# Unable connect to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a C# project with SQL Server 2008 R2 and the project runs with no problem on my local machine and when I publish it to the server Win2008 R2. But the project doesn't work and can't connect to the server with no error. All the database setting check and I enabled TCP/IP setting and etc. But still not worked. I think the problem is with connection string that is below. 
When pages going to connect to the database, nothing happened in browser and browser stick in loading mode (waiting for respond).

Connection string on my computer

```
Data Source =(Local);Initial Catalog=Bulk;Integrated Security=True;Timeout=0;Max Pool Size=5000;
```

Connection string on Windows server

```
Data Source=My Ip Windows Server,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Bulk;User ID=administrator;Password=My Windows Login Pass;Timeout=0;Max Pool Size=5000;
```

I got this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my connection string to this and problem solved.

```
public static string ConnectionString = "Data Source=My Ip,1433;Initial Catalog=My DataBase;UID=sa;Pwd=My Pass;Timeout=0;Max Pool Size=5000;";
```

In sql server management studio
Click "Security" => "Logins" => "sa" right-click and click properties
in the left side click "Status" and in the right side,Choose enable in login

Answer (score 2):

In your connection string of Server you have:

1. `Data Source=My Ip Windows Server,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;`
   [To connect via IP Address and Port of 1433 and over TCP/IP protocol](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/connect-via-an-ip-address/)
2. `Initial Catalog=Bulk;`
   `Bulk` is your database name
3. `User ID=administrator;Password=My Windows Login Pass;`
   Authenticate via SQL Server connection by `administrator` login user and its password.

I think your problem is in third part that you want to connect to SQL Server by your Windows user name; You can see valid logins of your SQL Server in Security branch of your registered server in SQL Server Management Studio that will shows your Windows user name like `Domain Name\User Name` so you need to change [`User Id` to that](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/trusted-connection-from-a-ce-device/).

Comment: If you want to use Windows authentication you simply leave credentials out of the connection string and specify integrated security. Sending username/password implies SQL authentication, which are a completely different set of credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Configure the Windows Firewall to Allow SQL Server Access. open port 1433 in windows firewall.
see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx). Or [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms175043.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Please Try to connect in your local Sqlserver With Live Login Detail,
If you are Success Then There should be Permission Need to set From the Live Hosting Server

if is it possible then please add the More specification.

Answer (score 0):

You should log the errors that occur, e.g. in Application_Error if it's actually an ASP.Net project.
Using the log you should get errormessages that hint you or enable you to give more details so nobody has to guess what your actual issue is.

Regarding your issue:
Did you give your Windows account the necessary READ/WRITE access on SQL Server?
On MS SQL Server the account needs access to:
1. Be added to the general Security/Logins for an actual match of Windows account to Login.
2. Be added to the specific database Security/Users tab with the necessary database role membership.

In addition to specifiying your Windows account + password in the connectionstring: maybe it's better to run the application pool using a service-account and use

```
Integrated Security=True
```

and remove

```
User ID=administrator;Password=My Windows Login Pass;
```